# Using the dcast() function following dplyr summarize()

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I've got a dataset of about 4,000 scores from four different archery events. There are two different equipment classes in the dataset: compound and recurve. I need to show some summary statistics grouped by "Event", but spread out in a table by the "Class".

Here's a bit of sample data:

```
> results
# A tibble: 4,478 x 8
    Year Event                 Class    Division Gender Organization Setting Score
   <dbl> <chr>                 <chr>    <chr>    <chr>  <chr>        <chr>   <dbl>
 1  2016 NFAA Indoor Nationals Compound Amateur  F      NFAA         Indoor    711
 2  2016 NFAA Indoor Nationals Compound Amateur  F      NFAA         Indoor    708
 3  2016 NFAA Indoor Nationals Compound Amateur  F      NFAA         Indoor    708
 4  2016 NFAA Indoor Nationals Compound Amateur  F      NFAA         Indoor    702
 5  2016 NFAA Indoor Nationals Compound Amateur  F      NFAA         Indoor    700
 6  2016 NFAA Indoor Nationals Compound Amateur  F      NFAA         Indoor    700
 7  2016 NFAA Indoor Nationals Compound Amateur  F      NFAA         Indoor    699
 8  2016 NFAA Indoor Nationals Compound Amateur  F      NFAA         Indoor    696
 9  2016 NFAA Indoor Nationals Compound Amateur  F      NFAA         Indoor    694
10  2016 NFAA Indoor Nationals Compound Amateur  F      NFAA         Indoor    690
# … with 4,468 more rows
```

I'm using the following code to generate the 10th, 50th, and 90th percentiles for each equipment class at the four events.

```
percentile_summaries <- results %>%
  select(Event, Class, Score) %>%
  group_by(Event, Class) %>%
  summarize(p10=quantile(Score, c(.10)),
            p50=median(Score),
            p90=quantile(Score, c(.90))
            )
```

That code produces the following output:

```
> percentile_summaries
# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   Event [?]
  Event                         Class      p10   p50   p90
  <chr>                         <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 NFAA Field Nationals          Compound  504.  538   555 
2 NFAA Field Nationals          Recurve   398.  463   496.
3 NFAA Indoor Nationals         Compound  656   704   718 
4 NFAA Indoor Nationals         Recurve   464.  554.  626 
5 USA Archery Indoor Nationals  Compound 1026. 1116  1166 
6 USA Archery Indoor Nationals  Recurve   706   959  1105 
7 USA Archery Outdoor Nationals Compound 1148. 1328. 1398 
8 USA Archery Outdoor Nationals Recurve   860. 1096  1252.
```

Now I'd like to spread those percentiles so I have the three percentiles for compound and the three percentiles for recurve in a row with the event name. Eventually, I'll generate an HTML table that looks (roughly) like this:

```
                              Compound                 Recurve
                         p10     p50     p90     p10     p50     p90
NFAA Field Nationals     504     538     555     398     463     496
NFAA Indoor Nationals    656     704     718     464     554     626
etc.
```

So far, the last step of spreading that data is eluding me. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Please use `dput(head(results,20))` to provide sample data.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will do so in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is the following. Starting from your `percentile_summaries` tibble, you can use the package `data.table` to use the function `dcast` with multiple columns in the `value.var` argument, i.e.

```
library(data.table)
df <- dcast(setDT(percentile_summaries), Event ~ Class, value.var = c("p10", "p50", "p90"))
```

Output:

```
                        Event p10_Compound p10_Recurve p50_Compound p50_Recurve p90_Compound p90_Recurve
         NFAA_Field_Nationals          504         398          538         463          555         496
        NFAA_Indoor_Nationals          656         464          704         554          718         626
 USA_Archery_Indoor_Nationals         1026         706         1116         959         1166        1105
USA_Archery_Outdoor_Nationals         1148         860         1328        1096         1398        1252
```

Here the order of the columns is not the desired one, as "Compound" and "Recurve" are alternated. To order them, use simply

```
df[,c(1,2,4,6,3,5,7)]
```

**Output:**

```
                        Event p10_Compound p50_Compound p90_Compound p10_Recurve p50_Recurve p90_Recurve
         NFAA_Field_Nationals          504          538          555         398         463         496
        NFAA_Indoor_Nationals          656          704          718         464         554         626
 USA_Archery_Indoor_Nationals         1026         1116         1166         706         959        1105
USA_Archery_Outdoor_Nationals         1148         1328         1398         860        1096        1252
```

Then you can proceed with the HTML table you want.